# Programa em Python com um problema peculiar de condição if e else

Tags: python

Olá, senhores(as).

Sou iniciante em programação e estou aprendendo Python.

Queria tirar uma dúvida sobre um programa que criei.

O programa deve criar uma tupla totalmente preenchida com uma contagem por extensão, de zero a vinte.
O programa deverá então ler um número pelo teclado (entre 0 a 20) e mostrá-lo por extenso. Ao final do programa deve-se mostrar se o usuário deseja continuar digitando (Condições S (para sim) ou N (para não).

Eu consegui concluir o programa parcialmente, mas observem que quando coloco o programa pra "rodar" o erro de não identificação da condição "if" é esquecido na primeira digitação do usuário após o mesmo ter digitado uma opção inexistente para o programa. Somente na segunda vez que ele digita N (dizendo que NÃO deseja continuar) é quando o programa realmente finaliza[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Segue o erro na imagem:

Comment: Por favor, [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código fonte. Por ler mais sobre em [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485).

Comment: "colocar o código fonte" é colocar o código fonte como _texto_ - não como imagem. Ao colar código como imagem, quem for tentar colaborar não pode copiar trechos do seu código para responder, ou mesmo criar uma versão que funcione - além de estar limitado só ao código que aparece na tela.. 
Em suma: edita a pergunta, remova essa imagem, cole o seu codigo fonte, selecione-o e clique no botão `{}` para formatar o código. Repita o processo com o traceback (mensagem de erro).

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, isso acontece devido a natureza dos seus `if's`, um deles trata se a variável é 'N' e a outra trata se a variável não for 'N', ou seja, se eu pressionar 'N' o primeiro `if` será verdadeiro, e o segundo também será verdadeiro.

Considere utilizar um `if-elif`